# Recursive retry in Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Now I am learning how to write JavaScript code with `promise`. Here is my case, the `deliverMessage` function in `Sender` try to connect with amqp. If success, then call `publish_` to send messages. Otherwise, call `reconnect_` to reconnect to `amqp` after 3 seconds. The codes are as following,

```
Sender.prototype.reconnect_ = function( err ) {
    console.error('MessageBus disconnected, attempting to reconnect' + err);
    this.createFakeChannel_();
    return setTimeout( this.deliverMessage.bind(this), 3000);
};
Sender.prototype.deliverMessage = function() {
    when(amqp.connect( this.addr_ ))
        .with( this )
        .then( this.createChannel_ )
        .then( this.createExchange_ )
        .then( this.handleUnrouteableMessages_ )
        .then( this.handleDisconnections_ )
        .catch( this.reconnect_ )
        .done( this.publish_ ); //? publish_ is invoked in all case?
};
```

Actually, whether the connection is succeeded or failed, `publish_` is called anyway. Could anyone help me how to implement it with `promise`?

Comment: have you tried ```.then( this.handleDisconnections_ ).then(this.publish_, this.reconnect_)```?

Comment: @mido22 - but probably need something that doesn't keep this loop going forever retrying every 3 seconds.  Perhaps a max number of retries before giving up.

Comment: @jfriend00 how about my answer now, I have added a parameter to take care of the number of attempts...

Comment: The `catch` processes the promise "successfully" (unless it itself throws), which means chained `then`'s (including the `done`) will operate on the fulfilled/resolved result of `reconnect_`. If you want the promise to "remain" in rejected state, one simple way is to rethrow the error inside `reconnect_`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do that like...

```
Sender.prototype.reconnect_ = function( err, attempt ) {
    attempt = attempt || 0;
    attempt++;
    if(attempt>3){  // change it to whatever value you prefer
        throw err;
    }
    console.error('MessageBus disconnected, attempting to reconnect' + err);
    this.createFakeChannel_();
    return setTimeout( this.deliverMessage.bind(this, attempt ), 3000);
};
Sender.prototype.deliverMessage = function(attempt) {
    when(amqp.connect( this.addr_ ))
        .with( this )
        .then( this.createChannel_ )
        .then( this.createExchange_ )
        .then( this.handleUnrouteableMessages_ )
        .then( this.handleDisconnections_ )
        .then( this.publish_, function(err){
            this.reconnect_(err, attempt);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout doesn't return a promise so that's not gonna work.

```
Sender.prototype.reconnect_ = function( err ) {
    console.error('MessageBus disconnected, attempting to reconnect' + err);
    this.createFakeChannel_();
    return when.delay(3000).with(this).then(this.deliverMessage);
};
Sender.prototype.deliverMessage = function () {
    when(amqp.connect( this.addr_ ))
        .with( this )
        .then( this.createChannel_ )
        .then( this.createExchange_ )
        .then( this.handleUnrouteableMessages_ )
        .then( this.handleDisconnections_ )
        .then( this.publish_ )
        .catch( this.reconnect_ );
};
```

Your placement of done was wrong (in fact you should never use done with when.js anyway but that's another story), it will always be called as you say.

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting here](https://github.com/cujojs/when/issues/426)

`Implementing a retry pattern is fairly simple with promises and recursion. The key is ensuring that the promise chain is unbroken. In your example, the call to setTimeout severs the promise chain by initiating a new asynchronous call to deliveryMessage that is outside the promise chain. reconnect also returns the the result of setTimeout immediately.`

My codes are changed as following

```
Sender.prototype.deliverMessage = function ( key, msg ) {
    return this
        .tryConnect_( this.attempts_, this.retryDelay_ )
        .with(this)
        .then(function() {
            return this.publish_( key, msg );
        }).catch( function( e ) {
            console.log( e );
        });
}

Sender.prototype.retryConnect_ = function( attempts, retryDelay, err ) {
    if (attempts === 0) {
        console.error('Sender: MessageBus disconnected, attempted to reconnect. Err:' + err);
        return when.reject( new Error('Max reconnect attempts exceeded, connection failed'));
    }

    return when( 'retry' )
        .with( this )
        .delay( retryDelay )
        .then(function() { 
            return this.tryConnect_( attempts - 1, this.retryDelay_ ); 
        })
}

Sender.prototype.tryConnect_ = function( attempts, retryDelay ) {
    return when(amqp.connect( this.addr_ ))
        .with( this )
        .then( this.createChannel_ )
        .then( this.createExchange_ )
        .then( this.handleUnrouteableMessages_ )
        .then( this.handleDisconnections_ )
        .catch( function( e ) {
            return this.retryConnect_( attempts, retryDelay, e );
        });
};
```